# What is the execution order for this BPD?

Tags: bpmn

I have the following diagram:

[image]

Could you please help me understanding why:

- if C1&C2 are true, the second inclusive gateway will receive first the output from Task 3/Task 4;
- if C1 true, C2 false, the second inclusive gateway will receive the output from Task 3 before the output from Task 2;

What I don’t understand is the execution order.How do we know what activity is finished first given the above info?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the diagram there is no way to predict which activity will be finished first.

What we know is that "Task 2" will be executed and additionally "Task 3" and/or "Task 4" might be executed in parallel to "Task 2".

The second inclusive gateway will receive the token from one of the previously activated tasks in no particular order. It all depends on the tasks execution duration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [Camunda Docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/bpmn20/gateways/) says on gateways:

> Gateways control token flow in a process. They allow modeling
>   decisions based on data and events as well as fork / join **concurrency**.

So complementing Antoine Mottier's answer, I would even say that the diagram *deliberately* gives no particular execution order, but shows that the tasks 2 and 3 and/or 4 all run in parallel.

Also refer to their documentation of [parallel gateways](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/bpmn20/gateways/parallel-gateway/) and [inclusive gateways](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/bpmn20/gateways/inclusive-gateway/).